# How to attach main camera to script component of a prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a prefab which is an item drop and a timer attached to the main camera. When the player collides with the item, I need the item to destroy then add time to the timer.

The itemdrop handling script looks like this:

```
   public LifeTimer LifeTimer;

   // Destroy sprite once player collides into it 
   void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
       if(col.gameObject.name=="Player"){
           Destroy(gameObject);
           LifeTimer.currentTime += 10;

       }
   }
```

The life timer is a reference to my script as follow which is attached to the main camera.

```
public class LifeTimer : MonoBehaviour
{


    // Once level initializes, start current time to starting time
    public float currentTime = 0f;
    public float startingTime = 10f;

    [SerializeField] Text lifeTimerText;

    void Start(){
        currentTime = startingTime;
    }

    void Update(){

        // Decrement time per second every second
        currentTime -= 1*Time.deltaTime;
        // Set currentime to text on screen
        lifeTimerText.text = currentTime.ToString ("0");

        // Load Game Over Screen when time goes to 0
       if(currentTime <= 0){
            Application.LoadLevel(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I realized I can't attach the main camera to the life timer component of the item drop script because the item prefab is not instantiated yet. What would be the best way to do what I'm trying to do, which is to add time to the timer. The on collision and destroying aspect works perfectly.

Thank you for any guidance

**Working solution:**

```
public class itemdrop : MonoBehaviour
{
    LifeTimer lifeTimer;

   void Start(){
       lifeTimer = Camera.main.GetComponent<LifeTimer>();

   }

   // Destroy sprite once player collides into it 
   void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
       if(col.gameObject.name=="Player"){
           Destroy(gameObject);
           lifeTimer.currentTime += 10;
       }
   }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the MainCamera with `Camera.main`
Just get a reference to the Camera object in the `Start()` Method with `Camera.main` and call the reference.

Edit your ItemDrop Script as follows:

```
public LifeTimer LifeTimer;

void Start() {
    LifeTimer = Camera.main.GetComponent<LifeTimer>();
}

// Destroy sprite once player collides into it 
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
   if(col.gameObject.name=="Player"){
       Destroy(gameObject);
       LifeTimer.currentTime += 10;

   }
```

}

Comment: In the start method of itemdrop script? Not sure I understand how to proceed with this. I create a reference to the Camera in the item drop script? Then should i change the LifeTimer to something like Camera.main.Lifetimer?

Comment: Exactly. You do something like: LifeTimer = Camera.main.GetComponent<LifeTimer>()